# sql server find date difference in days input date format is dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I am developing one project for which i want my date format in `dd/mm/yyyy` (Indian Format/ British Format). In my Database Table i have used string data type for this field.

I have 2 fields In_date and Out_date through these I am calculating Total_days.

Now I want to calculate difference between these 2 dates in days. The default format of SQL Server is `mm/dd/yyyy`. whenever I execute

```
select Datediff(DAY, 'In_date', 'Out_date') from Table;
```

it gives me error Error converting date from/to string. but when i execute

```
select Datediff(DAY, '05/28/2013', '05/26/2013') from Table;
```

it gives me perfect answer.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You should only store dates in your database as `DateTime`s. This will allow you to properly compare dates. Formatting should be handled in your application layer.

Comment: Yes brother you are right but it was requirement of customer to store date in different field and time in different field and in the format dd/mm/yyyy and time in hh:mm.

Comment: in that case, remove the apostrophe's around your column names in the first example and it should work... but it's badly designed. tell your customers they shouldn't dictate technical requirements :-)

Comment: ya bro. I have told them so many times but they don't listen. What to do in the end 'Customer is King' isn't it?

Comment: If the customer is demanding something that is an unreasonable or inappropriate technical approach, charge them accordingly. Set a lower price for them letting you do things correctly, and higher if they're dictating the underlying technical details that should should be handling.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
SET DATEFORMAT mdy
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '05/28/2013', '05/26/2013')
```

But desirable to use ISO date format (*ymd*):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '20130528', '20130526')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this  :

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;

select Datediff(DAY, In_date, Out_date) from Table;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to convert the column names to dates and they are not dates. Remove the apostrophes from around 'In_date' and 'Out_date' and it will recognize them as columns and not strings.

```
select Datediff(DAY, In_date, Out_date) from Table
```

Comment: doesn't work. my format is in dd/mm/yyyy and sql server's is mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

```
select Datediff(DAY, In_date, Out_date) from Table;
```